# Proof that order of integration does not matter for non-continuous functions

Tags: integration, continuity, indefinite-integrals

For continuous functions of several variable, by [Young's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives) the order of integration (i.e. "antiderivation") does not matter so that for instance

$$ \int \left(\int f(x,y)~ dx\right) ~dy = \int \left(\int f(x,y) ~dy\right) ~dx $$

Now we also know that some non-continuous functions have antiderivatives (see [the wikipedia article on antiderivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative#Antiderivatives_of_non-continuous_functions)).

My question is :

- Is it also true in general that the order of integration does not matter for these non-continuous functions which have antiderivative?
- Does anyone know of a proof?
- If not true in general, does there exists additional conditions such that the result would hold for non-continuous functions?

This question emerge from spliting [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685376/can-you-always-inverse-the-order-of-integration-of-an-indefinite-integrals) into two because I thought it was too messy.

Comment: Perhaps Fubini's Theorem is what you are looking for...